# How do you eliminate items from nested lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Given a list of ranked ballots and a list of candidates to eliminate, I need to return a new list of ranked ballots where all the candidates in the list of candidates to eliminate have been removed.

This is the code I've tried so far

```
import doctest 

def eliminate_candidate(ballots, to_eliminate):
    '''
    (list, list) -> list

    >>> eliminate_candidate([['NDP', 'LIBERAL'], ['GREEN', 'NDP'], \
    ['NDP', 'BLOC']], ['NDP', 'LIBERAL'])
    [[], ['GREEN'], ['BLOC']]
    >>> eliminate_candidate([], [])
    []
    >>> eliminate_candidate([[]], [])
    [[]]
    '''
    new_list = []

    # Copy ballots onto new list
    for item in ballots:
        new_list.append(item)

    for item in new_list:
        for element in item:
            if element in to_eliminate:
                item.remove(element)

    return new_list
```

My first doctest is failing, giving me this output instead:

```
[['LIBERAL'], ['GREEN'], ['BLOC']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function required. It searches through the sublists:

```
def eliminate_candidate(ballots, to_eliminate):
    return [[party for party in ballot if party not in to_eliminate] for ballot in ballots]

ballots = [['NDP', 'LIBERAL'], ['GREEN', 'NDP'], ['NDP', 'BLOC']]
to_eliminate = ['NDP', 'LIBERAL']

print(eliminate_candidate(ballots, to_eliminate))
```

Output:

```
[[], ['GREEN'], ['BLOC']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sets` becomes pretty easy!

```
ballots = [['NDP', 'LIBERAL'], ['GREEN', 'NDP'], ['NDP', 'BLOC']]
to_eliminate = ['NDP', 'LIBERAL']

result = [list(set(x) - set(to_eliminate)) for x in ballots]
result
[[], ['GREEN'], ['BLOC']]
```

Or:

```
result = [list(set(x).difference(to_eliminate)) for x in ballots]
result
[[], ['GREEN'], ['BLOC']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ballots = [['NDP', 'LIBERAL'], ['GREEN', 'NDP'], ['NDP', 'BLOC']]
to_eliminate = ['NDP', 'LIBERAL']

res = [[element for element in b if element not in to_eliminate] for b in ballots]
print(res)
```

prints

```
[[], ['GREEN'], ['BLOC']]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as the name of a variable!

Comment: Your output seems to be different to the requirement stated by the OP.

Comment: But that his output is not as the stated requirement.